# hadoop - How can i use data in memory as input format?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a mapreduce job, and I have the input that I want to pass to the mappers in the memory.

The usual method to pass input to the mappers is via the Hdfs - sequencefileinputformat or Textfileinputformat. These inputformats need to have files in the fdfs which will be loaded and splitted to the mappers

I cant find a simple method to pass, lets say  List of elemnts to the mappers.
I find myself having to wrtite these elements to disk and then use fileinputformat.

any solution?

I'm writing the code in java offcourse.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input format is not have to load data from the disk or file system.
There are also input formats reading data from other systems like HBase or (http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapred/TableInputFormat.html) where data is not implied to sit on the disk. It only is implied to be available via some API on all nodes of the cluster. 
So you need to implement input format which splits data in your own logic (as soon as there is no files it is your own task) and to chop the data into records 
.
Please note that your in memory data source should be distributed and run on all nodes of the cluster. You will also need some efficient IPC mechanism to pass data from your process to the Mapper process. 
I would be glad also to know what is your case which leads to this unusual requirement.

Comment: I have a simple code that gets a path in the filesystem, and returns a list of all the files under the path. I want to run this code on my cluster to have better results. so i Want to have this code in the mapper, and have the reducer just to collect. I want to give each mapper as an input a path on which it will run. I have a list of root paths in memory and I want to pass them as input to my mapper.
This is the usecase. maybe there's a better way to do this in map reduce.